# c++ Ordinary differential equation system

Tags: c++

Hi:) I try to solve an equation system of ordinary differential functions in C++ (first order differential equations) by the fourth- order Runge-Kutta methode. They are the ODEs of two coupled FitzHugh-Nagumo model neurons, it describes the electrostatic potential across the cell membrane of a neuron. By running this code I'm getting a segementation fault. Can everyone help me, what I sholud change in the code?

```
float f1(float x1, float y1, float gamma1, float x2){
  float xx1;
  xx1 = pow(x1,3);
  return x1-(xx1/3)-y1+gamma1*x2;
}

float f2(float eps1, float x1, float a1) {
  return eps1 * (x1 +a1);
}

float f3(float x2, float y2, float gamma2, float x1) {
  return x2-(x2/3)-y2+gamma2*x1;
}

float f4(float eps2, float x2, float a2) {
  return eps2 * (x2 +a2);
}


int main(){

 // Set the parameters for the FitzHugh-Nagumo model
 // Either read them from the parameter.dat 
 // or simply hard code them here.
float eps1 = 0.1;
float gamma1 = 2.0;
float eps2 = 0.1;
float gamma2 = -1.5;

float a1[3] = {1.3, 1.3, 1.3};
float a2[3] = {1.3, 0.5, 0.25};

float LO = -2;
float HI = 2;

vector<float> fx1;
vector<float> fx2;
vector<float> fy1;
vector<float> fy2;

fx1[0] = LO + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(HI-LO)));
fx2[0] = LO + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(HI-LO)));

fy1[0] = LO + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(HI-LO)));
fy2[0] = LO + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(HI-LO)));

const int number_steps = 5000;
const float step_size = 0.05;

for(int i=0; i <= number_steps; ++i){

  float x1_1 = f1(fx1[i],fy1[i],gamma1,fx2[i]); 
  float y1_1 = f2(eps1, fx1[i], a1[0]); 
  float x2_1 = f3(fx2[i],fy2[i],gamma2,fx1[i]); 
  float y2_1 = f4(eps2,fx2[i],a2[0]); 

  float x1_2 = f1(fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_1),fy1[i]+((step_size/2)*y1_1),gamma1,fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_1)); 
  float y1_2 = f2(eps1, fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_1), a1[0]); 
  float x2_2 = f3(fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_1),fy2[i]+((step_size/2)*y2_1),gamma2,fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_1)); 
  float y2_2 = f4(eps2,fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_1),a2[0]); 

  float x1_3 = f1(fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_2),fy1[i]+((step_size/2)*y1_2),gamma1,fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_2)); 
  float y1_3 = f2(eps1, fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_2), a1[0]); 
  float x2_3 = f3(fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_2),fy2[i]+((step_size/2)*y2_2),gamma2,fx1[i]+((step_size/2)*x1_2)); 
  float y2_3 = f4(eps2,fx2[i]+((step_size/2)*x2_2),a2[0]); 

  float x1_4 = f1(fx1[i]+(step_size*x1_3),fy1[i]+(step_size*y1_3),gamma1,fx2[i]+(step_size*x2_3)); 
  float y1_4 = f2(eps1, fx1[i]+(step_size*x1_3), a1[0]); 
  float x2_4 = f3(fx2[i]+(step_size*x2_3),fy2[i]+(step_size*y2_3),gamma2,fx1[i]+(step_size*x1_3)); 
  float y2_4 = f4(eps2,fx2[i]+(step_size*x2_3),a2[0]); 

  fx1[i+1] = fx1[i] +(step_size/6)*(x1_1 + 2*x1_2 + 2*x1_3 + x1_4);
  fy1[i+1] = fy1[i] +(step_size/6)*(y1_1 + 2*y1_2 + 2*y1_3 + y1_4);
  fx2[i+1] = fx2[i] +(step_size/6)*(x2_1 + 2*x2_2 + 2*x2_3 + x2_4);
  fy2[i+1] = fy2[i] +(step_size/6)*(y2_1 + 2*y2_2 + 2*y2_3 + y2_4);

}
```

Comment: Assigning to non-existing vector elements does not expand the vector - it is undefined.

Comment: There are some tools that help detect such errors. The error message in this case is not particularly good, but at least it points you to the correct line: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68b2dcf2efa0389f

Answer (score 1):

Allocate your data.

```
vector<float> fx1;
vector<float> fx2;
vector<float> fy1;
vector<float> fy2;
```

Creates empty vectors that you are then trying to access, considering that the data is already available. It is not.

Use:

```
vector<float> fx1(number_steps+2);
vector<float> fx2(number_steps+2);
vector<float> fy1(number_steps+2);
vector<float> fy2(number_steps+2);
```